# hibernate: full join using annotations

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I want to perform full outer join on two table using hibernate.

These two tables don't have any foreign key primary key relation.

**table 1.**

```
valcode nvarchar2(10)
value number
datemodified date
```

**table 2**

```
id number
result nvarchar2(10)
```

**SQL query:**

```
select a.valcode, b.id, b.result from table1 a,table2 b (+) on a.valcode=b.id order by a.valcode
```

How do I convert this query to a hibernate query with annotations in the table class?

Comment: yes the classes are mapped with annotaions for columns and primary keys.The part where you relate the two tables. and since i a have two beans for the two tables i dont know how to write my hql query.

Comment: We would need the mapping in order to help.

Comment: You join clause is `a.valcode=b.id` but they both are different data types.Is that a working SQL?

Answer (score 0):

That is indeed a good question. I did not come by this issue yet; so, I am also interesting in any possible solution.

If I understood right, there is not any “natural” relationship between these two tables. Therefore, I am not really sure if there is an easy and efficient way to do it with Hibernate using HQL or Criteria.

How about if you create a view using the SQL you want and map this view with a Hibernate Entity?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know from Hibernate documentation, you can use the fetch attribute on the relation annotation and set it to `FetchType.EAGER`:

> You have the ability to either eagerly or lazily fetch associated
>   entities. The fetch parameter can be set to `FetchType.LAZY` or
>   `FetchType.EAGER`. EAGER will try to use an outer join select to
>   retrieve the associated object, while LAZY will only trigger a select
>   when the associated object is accessed for the first time.
>   `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToMany` associations are defaulted to LAZY and
>   `@OneToOne` and `@ManyToOne` are defaulted to EAGER.

You can find the full documentation [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/pdf/hibernate_reference.pdf).